# Align target to middle when using <a href="#id">

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I'm using

```
<a href="#id"> 
.
.
.
<dl>
 <dt></dt>
 <dd></dd>
 <dd id="id"></dd>
 <dd></dd>
<dl>
```

The page scrolls to target id in the way that the target id shows-up in the top of the page. Is it possible that the target will be shown in the middle of the page?

P.S. I would prefer to achieve this by using css if possible.

Comment: Have you found a solution using CSS?

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fju73/)**

with JQuery this can be achieved as follows

**jQuery**

```
$('.clickme').on("click", function () {
    var docHeight = $(window).height()/2;
    alert(docHeight)
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($('#target').offset().top - docHeight)+11
        // 11 is height of #target/2 or height of first line/2 for accuracy
    }, 1000);
});
```

Hope this helps